# is the phrase 'accelerate success' proper english?

Tags: grammar

Is the phrase 'accelerate success' proper english?  Any suggested phrases to replace if this is not?

Comment: I'd prefer "**expedite**" (make *sooner*) to "**accelerate**" (make *faster*), but I've see "accelerate success" often enough as a slogan, I'd say it's gained acceptance.

Comment: Please find *anything* else. That phrase stinks of marketing buzzword bingo games, ranking right up there with *leveraging synergies*.

Comment: No, it is not proper english, because english is the spin you put on the ball in billiards, and this phrase does not put any spin on the ball in billiards. Like, *at all*.

Comment: Tom:  Reg is pointing out that the language English is capitalized.

Comment: @RegDwigHt: Could you like, BE any more droll? Don

Comment: Then there's the old fashioned word "hasten." To "hasten success" has a certain cachet. Don

Comment: Also see  [What is better terminology for the phrase 'Accelerate success'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/194218),

Answer (score 1):

Syntactically, it's fine.

Semantically, it's jargon.