# What is better terminology for the phrase 'Accelerate success'?

Tags: grammar

What is the correct  terminology for a person or group to 'accelerate the success' for an entire organization?

Comment: In any case, success is an **event,** not a process that can be 'accelerated.'

Comment: Expeditors. "He is also the president's chief expediter in charge of completing key infrastructure and agricultural development projects." See OxfordDictionaries online  http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/expedite

Comment: "Accelerate the success" roughly translates to "I have read too many badly written books on management and now suffer terminal cognitive deficiency, please ignore everything I say"

Answer (score 1):

expedite success may be better?

> make (an action or process) happen sooner or be accomplished more quickly.
>   -- [Google Dictionary](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=define%20expedite&gws_rd=ssl)

Answer (score 0):

In his famous work on accelerating the success of organizations - [Good to Great](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Good_to_Great), author [Jim Collins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_C._Collins) dubs this "the flywheel effect."

In a nutshell, the [flywheel effect](http://www.inc.com/jeff-haden/the-best-from-the-brightest-jim-collins-flywheel.html) suggests that it is difficult to start a successful pattern, but that by making the slow efforts, success builds on itself, and can continue to be accelerated by continual care an maintenance. It is a formula for accelerating success, and will be recognized by most business people as a Jim Collins metaphor, which may communicate exactly what you are intending.

When talking about the efforts needed to accelerate the success of the organziation, Collins speaks of "pushing the flywheel" or "ratcheting the flywheel."

A [Ratchet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratchet_(device)) communicates "[ratchetting up](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/british/ratchet-sth-up-down)" which is also what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

Really I think the best answer here is ..

> "accelerate towards success"

or just

> "accelerate to success"

Reason? Quite simply, "accelerate success" is meaningless as others have pointed out, since "success" has no first derivative.  So, it's very likely that the rah-rah writer in question meant (as it were) ..... "accelerate to success".

It's worth noting that business writing, or advertising writing, or populist book title writing (you can imagine this as a book title .. "Accelerate to Success!" or perhaps "Accelerate! to! Success!") ... It's worth noting that such writing **has no meaning or content**.

The person who wrote this has not the faintest idea what "acceleration" is nor what "success" is. It is, rather, **a combination of words** that ***sound exciting***.

Given that, as an editor let's say, the best bet would be to keep it as-is as much as possible.

Comment: Hey the perfect title  .. Successeleration!  Or Successeleration 2014 Now!